# How can I add seed data with correct relationships?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, foreign-keys, relationship, seed

I'm creating forum software using `Ruby on Rails`. I'm stuck on adding seed data to my database with the correct database relations.

A forum has many topics, and a topic belongs to a forum. That is a sample of one of the relationships.

So far, all I know how to do is create an instance that doesn't relate to any of the other tables in the database such as:

`Forum.create(attributes {})`

The point of this is so my nested routes will work properly: `/forums/:forum_id/topics/:id`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this.

In db/seeds.rb add something like:

```
form = Forum.create(attributes {})
form.topics.create(attributes{})
```

or

```
form = Forum.create(attributes {})
topic1 = Topic.create(attributes{})
topic2 = Topic.create(attributes{})

form.topics << topic1
form.topics << topic2
```

Then when you want to seed your db just run:

```
rake db:seed
```

Comment: If you want to drop database before, use rake db:reseed.